# Обновление ReportViewer

Tags: c#, sql-server, reportviewer

Проблема - при выводе отчёта С БД MS SQL выводится отчёт в форму, при добавлении данных в БД, в приложении при обновлении новые данные не отображаются, а при компиляции заново отображаются. Помогите решить проблему.